# Comparing two fields in django

Tags: django, field

can any body suggest me any idea about how can i compare two fields in django.
as i have two password fields in my forms.py file.
now i want to compare the two fields and if both are same then save the user in database
else append an error message to reenter the values again.

thanks

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-registration/0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override your form's `clean` method:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    password1=...
    password2=...
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data # individual field's clean methods have already been called
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must be identical.")

        return cleaned_data
```

See [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for more info.

You should also probably ALSO add some Javascript to check this on the client side - client side validation is no subsitute for server-side validation, but it is more responsive to the user and saves bandwidth.

Comment: Indentation seems off.

Comment: @Jarad it looks fine to me, but if you're seeing something I'm not please feel free to edit

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. Shouldn't the clean function be a method of the MyRegistrationForm class? If so, should it be indented to be within that class?